# String extension that modify self in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have written my fist extension in swift.
Here is code:

```
extension String
{
    // add padding
    // source: http://zh-wang.github.io/blog/2014/09/25/learning-swift-part-6/
    func alignRight(count: Int, pad: Character) -> String
    {
        let amountToPad = count - countElements(self)
        if amountToPad < 1 {
            return self
        }
        let padString = String(pad)
        var string = self
        for _ in 1...amountToPad {
            string = padString + string
        }
        return string
    }
}
```

This is working fine, I use it like this:

```
let a = "ddd"
let b = a.alignRight(5,  pad: "0") //  b is 00ddd
```

I would like to know is it possible to do it like this

```
var a = "ddd"
a.alignRight(5,  pad: "0") //  a is 00ddd
```

So I would like to make extension that is changing string, not making new one.
I have a problem because I can not do `self = "something"` in my extension.

Is this normal or I am missing something ?

Comment: If you just want an extension for the second version (the `var` one) you could just change the function to `mutating func alignRight...` and instead of returning a `String` just assign to `self` (so `return string` becomes `self = string` in your code)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use the `mutating` keyword.

```
mutating func alignRight(count: Int, pad: Character) {
// self = something works
}
```

See the [extensions' documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH24-XID_229) for more information.

Comment: An important point to mention here, this is only for structs.